# Is mov-immediate with a literal number with an "r" suffix like 42ae0000r valid in MASM?

Tags: x86, floating-point, masm, masm32

Here is the instruction:

```
    mov eax,42ae0000r
```

MASM gives no error but the code created is this:

```
    00000000  B8 19B6A492       mov eax,42ae0000r
```

From what the documentation says that the "r" suffix is for a floating point hex value. This result is different than what I get if I use the value as a initializer, like this:

```
    mytest4 real4 7d998000r
```

The code created is this:

```
    0000001B 7D998000       mytest4 real4 7d998000r
```

As you can see the results are different.

Answer (score 2):

To me this feels like a bug in the parser. That is, the assembler was supposed to generate an error but for some reason doesn't, and instead ends up parsing these numbers in a strange manner.

---

That is not the same as saying that the behavior is undefined. The results appear to be entirely predictable.

Let's look at a few basic examples:

```
mov ebx,0r
mov eax,1r
mov eax,2r
mov eax,10r
```

This assembles into:

```
00000405  BB52000000        mov ebx,0x52
0000040A  B85C000000        mov eax,0x5c
0000040F  B866000000        mov eax,0x66
00000414  B8B6000000        mov eax,0xb6
```

So we can see that `0r` equals 0x52. This is literally the letter R (its ASCII code).

If we look at the other rows we see a pattern: the generated value is always `'R'` plus the value preceeding the R times 10.
So `1r` == `'R' + 1*10`, `2r` == `'R' + 2*10`, etc. If the value becomes larger than the destination (in this case 32 bits) it is simply truncated to that size.

The base of these numbers is a bit curious, because you're allowed to use hexadecimal digits (0..F), but each digit is only worth 10 times more than the one to its right. So `11r` and `0Br` result in exactly the same value (`0xC0`).